# How do I include a namespace from a different folder using C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, amazon-mws

I have a C# project that using Amazons MWS API. My project needs to include a specific namespace for each API that Amazon makes available. The problem is Amazon has similar, or exactly the same names for the API files, even across APIs.

To combat naming issues I have created folders within my project for Reports, Orders, Feeds etc, with the API and underlying folder structure within. The problem I am now having is how do I refer to a specific API?

My folder structure is as follows:

```
AmazonConnectors
    |____Reports
         |____Attributes
                 |___[files]      
         |____Model
                 |___[files]
         [files]
```

The file I can refer to is MarketplaceWebService.cs located within the Reports folder.

The following statement works:

```
using MarketplaceWebService;
```

but what if I now want to refer to code within the Feeds API which is also contained within the AmazonConnectors project and has the same folder structure and file names as the Reports API?

Any searches I've done with keywords of Using and directories returns an obscene amount of unrelated material.

Is there an easy solution to keep all files within the same project, or will I need to separate each API into its own separate project within a solution?

----EDIT----

I tried adding both the reports and feeds API into the same project and as the namespace is the same, the duplicate methods ( which there are some ) give a duplicate definition error.

```
Error   49  The namespace 'MarketplaceWebService.Model' already contains a definition for 'Error'   C:\Programming_Projects\ARC\AmazonConnectors\Feeds\Model\Error.cs   28  18  AmazonConnectors
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example with two of the APIs?

Comment: Both the reports API and Feeds API reference MarketplaceWebService.cs, which is identical between the two of them and sahres the same namespace, however within each API's Model directory the API's differ. So MarketplaceWebService.Model does not point to a specific API.

Comment: Are you not able to change the namespace in the file before adding it to the project?

Comment: One of the model directories contains 82 separate files. Is the same across 8 different API's ( numbers of files vary, but theme is the same)

Comment: If you cannot, or don't want to be bothered with changing the namespace in every file, then I'd say your only other option would be to put them into different projects.

Comment: I was figuring as much, thanks for the attention SteveDog. I'll mark your post as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever have a naming conflict between two namespaces, you simply need to use the full namespace when you are referring to the type in the other namespace.  So if you have classes `A` and `B` in both namespaces `One` and `Two`, and class `B` in namespace Two needs to access class `A` from namespace `One`, it just needs to refer to it as `One.A` rather than just `A`.

Comment: I'm not so much concerned about a naming conflict as I am familiar with using aliases to resolve that issue - it's more of wanting to be certain that the API's are fully represented and nothing is missed/skipped due to not being able to specify which API explicitly, if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you...  Maybe if you provided a more specific example of your problem it might help clear things up

Comment: See the edit on the error message generated for further clarification - If needed I can provide additional information to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for elabrate (complex) folder structures. All the files can be in the same directory ( if one wants them to ), can name the files like so:

AmazonConnectors.File1.cs
.
.
AmazonConnectors.Reports.Attributes.File1.cs
AmazonConnectors.Reports.Attributes.File2.cs
.
.

And so are the name spaces.

You can use explicit naming or aliasing, e.g. :

using MarketPlaceWebService = AmazoneConnector.Model.MarketPlaceWebService;
or
just AmazoneConnector.Model.MarketPlaceWebService

Hope each file corresponds to a class and not just group of methods bundled together for convinience.

Comment: So no specific handling needs to be done to handle complex directory structures?